# ActionBarDrawerToggle not showing the correct icons

Tags: android

I am following the tutorial on http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html and am having problems with the ActionBarDrawerToggle. The documentation uses v4, but since that's deprecated I am trying to use the v7.

My problem is that I can not get a drawer/hamburger icon to show, but it always shows the up arrow, even when I am on the main activty that has no parents in the manifest.

This is my main activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.example.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    private String[] menuItems;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu);

            drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_list_item, menuItems));
            drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

            drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

            drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                drawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
            ) {
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };

            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
            getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, loginFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void selectMenuItem(int position)
    {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new DialFragment();
            break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new NumbersFragment();
            break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new LoginFragment();
            break;
        }

        getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .commit();

        drawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            selectMenuItem(position);
        }
    }
}
```

It works when I change:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

and when I change:

```
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,
        drawerLayout,
        R.string.drawer_open,
        R.string.drawer_close
    )
```

to

```
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
        )
```

After these changes I can see a correct hamburger icon that collapses/expands when the drawer is opened/closed, but I'd like to get the v7 to work. Any ideas?

Edit: just tried it on my phone (running the Android 5.0.1) and this shows the hamburger icon when the drawer is closed and animates into an arrow when opened. The emulator which I am using is API 15 / Android 4.0.3

Comment: you change v4 to v7 or v7 to v4? that part is not clear

Comment: Sorry, when I change v7 to v4, it works (but is deprecated). Updated main post.

Comment: have you tried this? getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); If you do  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); the burger icon should show

Comment: I get no icon at all when I try that and I can't open the drawer by clicking, just by sliding.

Comment: I will advise you use toolbars since that's what android suggests now. Can help you with that if you're interested. I made one recently with a recycler viewer

Comment: Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply was distracted by work. Take a look at my answer

Comment: Jesper87, did you ever solve this problem? I experience the same problem running on an emulator using API 15 (i.e the error where no hamburger icon is shown). But the ActionBarDrawerToggle works perfectly on 2 devices (running APIs 19 and 21) and 2 emulators (both using API 22). In other words, I see the problem on API 15 but not 19, 20 and 21. Note that I'm using android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle and not using appcompat libraries.

Comment: I ended up using v4 (import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout). It works on all API versions now.

Answer (score 0):

as ActionBarDrawerToggle has two different Signature but with the same name for constructor , and you used the constructor with 4 parameter

```
 drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,
        drawerLayout,
        R.string.drawer_open,
        R.string.drawer_close
    )
```

to solve that issue you could use the constructor method which accept toolbar

```
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,yourtoolbar
            drawerLayout,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
        )
```